# googlebot is crawling and my server sending me too many mails

Tags: http, web, web-crawler, googlebot

I am flooded by googlebot, i am getting a day approximately 25 mails from my hosting server saying some errors which do not make sense. one of them is this:

```
[Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /location/date-in-modersohnbrucke/101/

 File "/home/benjaminvisser/django-locate/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/home/benjaminvisser/locate/locate/home/views.py", line 462, in location
 location = Location.objects.get(id=lid)

 File "/home/benjaminvisser/django-locate/django/db/models/manager.py", line 131, in get
return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/home/benjaminvisser/django-locate/django/db/models/query.py", line 366, in get
% self.model._meta.object_name)

DoesNotExist: Location matching query does not exist.
```

but this url doesnot exist anymore in my webpage, why is google still crawling them? is there any way of saying to google that these urls DO NOT EXIST ANYMORE?

Comment: Are you using Wordpress on your site?

Comment: @KeesSonnema, no, just a normal page. no plugins.

Comment: Allright, Have you reindexed your page lately? Your problem could be solved by reindexing it.

Comment: You can check if google re(indexed) your page by typing site:[URLOfWebPage] into the google searchbox

Comment: @KeesSonnema, oh i dont know about it? how do i do it?

Comment: @KeesSonnema, site:www.locationyourdate.de like this?

Comment: Do it like this: site:[http://locationyourdate.de]

Comment: For more info about indexing, crawling and goopglebot look at this: http://blog.kissmetrics.com/get-google-to-index/